# show all user records except max date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hey guys I know there were many questions asked similar to my problem but I couldn't find the exact one to solve mine.

I have two tables in the database one containing user id, name, and if its an active user
the second table is with the id and date when he posted something.

example:

db_user (id, name, is_active)

db_post (user_id, udate)

I needed to see all records that are not (not MAX(date) ) the latest records.

I tried:

```
SELECT name, x.user_id, x.udate FROM db_post x
LEFT JOIN deb_user y
ON x.user_id = y.id

WHERE is_active=1 AND  x.date not in (SELECT t.udate FROM
(SELECT id, MAX(udate) AS udate FROM db_post
LEFT JOIN db_user e
ON id = e.id
GROUP BY ID)t)

ORDER BY id, udate
```

It works fine until some user's Max Date is others non-Max and it does not show all of these records.
Any ideas on how to fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all posts that are not the latest, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from db_post p
where p.udate < (select max(p2.udate)
                 from db_post p2
                 where p2.user_id = p.user_id
                );
```

Based on your question, I don't understand why the `db_user` table would be needed.  However, if you want to filter on the status, you can join that in.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! 
And yes I am adding db_user to find out if an account is still active to show me only active members' posts except the latest ones. Thanks!